# Looking for color profile and tint information - Falu Red

Tags: paint

I wish to mimic the traditional swedish summer house colour [Falu Red](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falu_red) for a DIY project at home but I cannot buy the traditional Falu or Falun Red paint - so does anyone know the colour or tint that would be closest so I can get the paint shop to mix me up a similar colour?

I'm hoping to walk into a standard paint shop and give them the details (from an answer, here) and the shop can then magically mix up a pot that's very very very similar :)

[image: example of falu red]

Answer (score 2):

Sherwin Williams SW 2914 Vermilion is as close to Falu Red as I have been able to find.  On a computer screen they are nearly indistinguishable.  My local Home Depot was able to make me a Behr Premium Plus Deep Base PP103 color sample of SW 2914.  Its a LOT cheaper than Sherwin Williams!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Nice answer; keep them coming!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to provide them with a physical sample with the color that you want.

If you don't have a real sample, next up would be to cite a color standard; unfortunately, there are lots of color standards out there, but [this page](http://www.perbang.dk/rgb/801818/) shows close matches to [Falu Red](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falu_red) in several of them.  (The Pantone system is widely used in the design industry so it might be most recognizable in the paint shop).

If that doesn't work, the paint shop will have color swatches that you can look at.  Even if they don't have a perfect match, you should be able to get them to make a custom mix of something that's partway between two other close matches.